# Remove text from multiple textareas only on first click

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have this code which removes the text from textarea **only on first click**. It works ok only until I wrote the second textarea tag which is:

```
<textarea id="textarea2" onfocus="checkOnFocus(this);" onblur="resetInitialText(this);">Your second message</textarea>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var flag = false;
  
      function setInitialText() {
        var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
        if (textarea.value == "") {
          textarea.value = text;
        }
      }
  
      function checkOnFocus(textarea) {
        if (!flag) textarea.value = "";
        flag = true;
      }
  
      function resetInitialText(textarea) {
        if (textarea.value == "") {
          textarea.value = text;
          flag = false;
        }
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="setInitialText();">
      <textarea id="textarea" onfocus="checkOnFocus(this);" onblur="resetInitialText(this);">Your first message</textarea>
      <textarea id="textarea2" onfocus="checkOnFocus(this);" onblur="resetInitialText(this);">Your second message</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would it hurt to indent your code?

Comment: Do you get any error in the console ?

Comment: You're using the same global `flag` for both textareas. Perfect example of why global state is to be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to do what I asked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title></title>  
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

$(function() {
    $("textarea").focus(function(event) {

          // Erase text from inside textarea
        $(this).text("");

          // Disable text erase
        $(this).unbind(event);
    });
});
//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="30">Enter text here.</textarea>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="30">Enter text here.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing from your answer, that you're ok with jquery, you could try the following as a very basic *placeholder*-solution:

```
$('[data-placeholder]').each(function () {
  var placeholder = $(this).data('placeholder');

  $(this).val(placeholder).on({
    focus: function () {
      $(this).val(function (_, value) {
        return value === placeholder ? '' : value;
      });
    },

    blur: function () {
      $(this).val(function (_, value) {
        return value === '' ? placeholder : value;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

with:

```
<textarea data-placeholder="Your first message"></textarea>
<textarea data-placeholder="Your second message"></textarea>
```

http://jsbin.com/iyobiy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have only one (global) flag and two textareas, so by the time the second call is made, the flag has already been set to true. Consider using an array or a dictionary type structure to create a generic implementation. One option would be to use an array in the global scope:

```
var textareasAlreadyHit = new Array();
```

Then every time you:

```
function checkOnFocus(textarea)
```

Instead of checking for the flag, check if the array contains the id of the textarea. If it does, do nothing. If it does not, remove the text from the textarea and add the id of the textarea to the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkOnFocus(textarea){
if(!flag)
textarea.value="";
flag=false;
}

function resetInitialText(textarea){
if(textarea.value==""){
textarea.value='text';
flag=false;
}
```

two changes are here

1>checkOnFocus()  method

```
flag=false;
```

2>resetInitialText() method

```
textarea.value='text';// make your own string to replace
```